# VBA_Combobox can not show the list

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, userform

I've made a `ComboBox` to choose the name of students. 
But when I click the triangle button to show the list of names, the area to choose is empty:

[image]

But when I tap some letters, the list shows up :

And the list keep adding the names, so it becomes longer and longer.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Dim MyArray As Variant
Dim Ctr As Integer
Dim listvar As Variant

MyArray = Array("Denis", "Daniel", "Jimmy", "David", "Eric")
For Ctr = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
    UserForm1.ComboBox1.AddItem MyArray(Ctr)
Next

listvar = ComboBox1.List

On Error Resume Next
If IsError(WorksheetFunction.Match(ComboBox1.Value, listvar, 0)) Then

    ComboBox1.AddItem ComboBox1.Value
End If

Operateur = ComboBox1.Text
UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

Besides, when I enter a new name like Mary, the list will remember every letter that I've tapped, like M, Ma, Mar, Mary.

So I just want when I click the triangle button, it can show me the names to choose, and when I write a new name, it can put it in the list the following times (without repeating names). Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add values to combobox earlier, when UserForm is displaying with `Initialize event` of `UserForm` but not with `Change event` of `ComboBox`.
Try something like this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim MyArray As Variant
Dim Ctr As Integer
Dim listvar As Variant

MyArray = Array("Denis", "Daniel", "Jimmy", "David", "Eric")
For Ctr = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
    UserForm1.ComboBox1.AddItem MyArray(Ctr)
Next

End Sub
```

End remove this section from your `ComboBox1_Change()` event.

---

Edit, simple example of how to use `KeyDown` event working with Enter button:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 13 Then
        Me.ComboBox1.AddItem Me.ComboBox1.Value

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok I see! And how can I add new names please?

Comment: you could try to make `MyArray` public, fill that array with `Initialize event` as presented, and next try to add new item with `ComboBox1_KeyDown event` after enter is pressed.

Comment: Yes, agree! But I've met a problem that the combobox can remember every letter I've tapped. Like I enter Mary, and it will remember M, Ma, Mar, and Mary at last. Do you have some idea about that?

Comment: therefore, as suggested above, use another event instead of `Change()`. I suggest to use `KeyDown()` event here...

Comment: Because the `keydown event` doesn't works with combobox, so is it normal?